# Failed silent auth - Login required Auth0

Tags: auth0

I am trying to implement login with Auth0 and looking at Dashboard -> Monitoring -> Logs, I can see that login is failing because it says `Failed silent auth - Login required`.

What is the solution to fix failed logins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Remove `prompt: 'none'` from the `authParams` you send.

In my case, I was using passwordless login with magic links and I was sending `prompt: 'none'` in the `authParams` of the body of the request to fetch `auth0.com/passwordless/start`.

I removed `prompt: 'none'` from the `authParams` and everything was good.

Comment: This is the official doc explaining the use of the prompt parameter for silent auth: https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/configure-silent-authentication#initiate-silent-authentication-requests